# Spark dataset write into 2 different directories

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset in spark partitioned by a column `ip`. Now I want to divide this dataset into 2 and write in HDFS such that if total partitions are `100` ie `ip=1 to ip=100` then each HDFS directory should contain 50 partitions each finally.

Input:

```
mydata/
mydata/ip=1
mydata/ip=2
mydata/ip=3
mydata/ip=4
.
.
mydata/ip=101
```

Result

```
mydata1/
mydata1/ip=1
mydata1/ip=3
.
.
mydata1/ip=50


mydata2/
mydata2/ip=51
mydata2/ip=4
mydata2/ip=100
```

Also while writing out how can I ensure that each directory mydata1 and mydata2 contain an equal distribution of data in terms of size. That means both directories should contain  eg 25Gb or data,
There shouldn't be a case where mydata1 contains 1GB and mydata2 contain49GB

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can be using bucketing. Read more about buckinting:
https://dwgeek.com/spark-sql-bucketing-on-dataframe-examples.html/

Comment: Thanks. How can I read the bucketed data using spark so that I can read from specific buckets, the above article only explains about writing to buckets? Also, like partitioning bucketing isn't creating a new directory for each bucket. Can we do that?